# Python - 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'compiler'

Tags: python, pip, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm using Python version 3.7 on a Windows 10, 64 bit system.

I'm trying to install a package named 'PyGObject' but, unable to do so. I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\mukar>pip install PyGObject
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/17/198a9d0eb0e89b5c7d2a9b4437eb40d62702ab771030cd79fc7141cb0d30/PyGObject-3.30.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pycairo>=1.11.1 in c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from PyGObject) (1.17.1)
Installing collected packages: PyGObject
  Running setup.py install for PyGObject ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\mukar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-srfolyoj\\PyGObject\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\mukar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-x4gbheju\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat\generictreemodel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat\pygtkcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pygtkcompat
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\docstring.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\pygtkcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\_error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\_gtktemplate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\_option.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\_ossighelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\_propertyhelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\_signalhelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    copying gi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\repository
    copying gi\repository\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\repository
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Gdk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GdkPixbuf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GIMarshallingTests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Gio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GLib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GObject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Gtk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\keysyms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Pango.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gi\overrides
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\mukar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-srfolyoj\PyGObject\setup.py", line 1189, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\mukar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-srfolyoj\PyGObject\setup.py", line 1184, in main
        zip_safe=False,
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\mukar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-srfolyoj\PyGObject\setup.py", line 1024, in run
        self._setup_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\mukar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-srfolyoj\PyGObject\setup.py", line 1010, in _setup_extensions
        add_ext_compiler_flags(gi_ext, compiler)
      File "C:\Users\mukar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-srfolyoj\PyGObject\setup.py", line 881, in add_ext_compiler_flags
        cache_key = compiler.compiler[0]
    AttributeError: 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'compiler'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\mukar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\mukar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-srfolyoj\\PyGObject\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\mukar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-x4gbheju\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mukar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-srfolyoj\PyGObject\
```

I tried searching everywhere but, couldn't find any solution to it. I even tried to install this on Python version 3.4 and 2.7, still no luck. I'm using PyCharm IDE.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with some additional build code in pygobject *setup.py*. Looking at the commit history version 3.28.0 should work:

```
pip install pygobject==3.28.0
```

I created a new issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/issues/275